# Get selected values in multiselect form field

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm updating a PHP form field from a dropdown (single value selected) to a multiselect (multiple values selected).

I have 2 DB tables, one where the complete list of team members reside, and the other where the selected team members reside.

On the PHP page, I want to get the values from the full team members table and show the full list as a multiselect form field.

Then I want to be able to get the values from the selected team member table and have them show as selected options in the full multiselect list mentioned above.

Any idea on how I would accomplish this?

Here's my code, although right now it just returns the full team member list without the selected values.

```
    $query = "SELECT walkername FROM Team_Management WHERE active=1 ORDER BY walkername ASC";  
                        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query) or die ("Couldn't execute query: ".mysqli_error($mysqli));
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $stmt->bind_result($walkers);
                        
                        echo "<div class='form-group'>";
                        echo "<label class='col-lg-3 control-label' for='Walkers'>Walkers:</label>";
                        echo "<div class='col-lg-5'>";
                        echo "<select multiple class='form-control' name='walkers[]' id='Walkers'>";
                    

                        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                          echo "<option value='$walkers'>$walkers</option>";
                        }
                        
                        echo "</select>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</div>";

                        $stmt->close();
```

** UPDATED **

So one thing that I should've added, is that the SELECTED_TEAM_MEMBERS field is a comma separated field.

#### TEAM_MANAGEMENT table

**id || walkername**

1  || John

2  || Kate

#### SELECTED_TEAM_MEMBER table

**cid || walkers**

1  | John,Ray,Kate

2  | Kate,Matt,Joe

In addition, each group in the walkers field in the SELECTED_TEAM_MEMBER table is tied to a unique client id (cid).

So how can I identify the selected walkers from the complete list in the TEAM_MANAGEMENT table by unique client id.

Comment: Without knowing your table structure and assuming i understood correctly the issue, i believe first you need to amend your sql query and to have a LEFT JOIN on the second table where you will return a field that will allow you to highlight(Select) the members that are present in both tables. By having this info available in your result you can add a simple condition in your while loop: like echo "<option value='$walkers'".(isset($result->value) ? 'selected':' '.">$walkers</option>";

Something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of your selected user with a boolean in your SQL request

```
SELECT walkername, 
       CASE WHEN **selected_team_members_name** > '' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END as is_selected 
FROM Team_Management 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN **SELECTED_TEAM_MEMBERS** ON **selected_team_members_name** = walkername
WHERE active=1 
ORDER BY walkername ASC
```

With **selected_team_members_name** the name of the column in your table and SELECTED_TEAM_MEMBERS the name of your table

And now $walker is as array with 2 key: walkername and is_selected

And after you can try a if to put them the attribute 'selected' when you write your 'option' tag

```
while ($stmt->fetch())
{
    $selected = "";
    if($walkers['is_selected'] == '1'){ //If your walker is selected
        $selected = "selected";
    }
    echo "<option ".$selected." value=".$walkers['walkername'].">".$walkers['walkername']."</option>";
}
```

I may not have understand the context but i hope i helped you.

Comment: This was definitely helpful and pointed me in a different direction where I was headed, but I'm still having difficulty.

Essentially the SELECTED_TEAM_MEMBERS table contain team members that are in a comma separated list and are assigned to each client id. So each client id has a unique set of team members assigned to them.

Would I use the find_in_set function for this or group_concat? Or a combination? The other difficulty is the join in that there are not common id's to join on.

Comment: Yes you can use 'find_in_set' to see if your walkername is in the list (with a case when then else like i did) to get a 'boolean' (which is a string) 

And for your relation you can look for 'CROSS JOIN' that may help you

Comment: Do you need help with the request or it will be ok for you ?

You can use a GROUP BY at the end AND 'HAVING' claus to get only the line when your walker is in the selected team because CROSS JOIN make all combination